Accessing iframe after page loaded
I was trying to add a iframe and connect to google maps after the page loaded like below
<iframe width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?width=100%25&amp;height=600&amp;hl=en&amp;q=1%20Grafton%20Street,%20Dublin,%20Ireland+(My%20Business%20Name)&amp;t=&amp;z=14&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;iwloc=B&amp;output=embed"></iframe>

but I got this message from the console
Refused to frame 'https://www.google.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' blob: data:".

I tried adding
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src 'self' blob: data:">

to the hearder which should grant the content that the console told me, but it didn't work.
Then I took a look at the header of the page response
Content-Security-Policy:
  default-src 'self'; 
  connect-src 'self'; 
  font-src 'self' data:; 
  frame-src 'self' blob: data:; 
  img-src 'self' blob: data:; 
  media-src 'self'; 
  object-src 'self' blob: data:; 
  script-src 'self' blob: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://accounts.google.com/; 
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
  frame-ancestors 'self' ;

but I found the policy frame-src 'self' blob: data: on the 4th line.
I also tried adding the frame on other websites, which works, but only this website won't work.
I don't really why it's still saying the same error. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Google and many of it's other services have a policy of not letting their websites be displaced as an iframe in order to protect users from iframe injection attacks.
https://www.how2lab.com/internet/security/iframe-hacking
Any approach you use won't work in this situation. Why not instead use SerpAPI if you want to interact with google on your site?
https://serpapi.com/

Actually I was going to access google map, so the serpapi probably won't work for my case. And sorry for not clearly describing the problem.

And also other websites like Wikipedia, GitHub, Youtube, etc. will not work as well.

@知識日常KnowScratcher it works on Wikipedia.

I meant websites like wikipedia, etc. can access the frame, but the website I wanted to add the frame can't display the map frame.
